# Python ElementTree ParseError

Tags: python, xml, xmlparser, big-data, elementtree

Доброго времени суток всем. Работаю с парсингом тяжелых файлов 4-10гб, некоторые из них хорошо разбираются парсером, а в других бросается исключение:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 16
```

Фрагмент кода:

```
events = ("start",)
for event, elem in ElementTree.iterparse(file_name, events=events):
    ...
```

Видел решение **подобной** проблемы с помощью кодировки, но тут я не знаю как её поставить.

**UPD:**
Посмотрел, что там в самом xml, а там знаки `"` заменяются на `&quot;`
Как это возможно исправить?
Я пытался пройтись по всему файлу и заменить все `&quot;` на `"`, но это не помогло.

Прилагаю часть файла:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<DATA FORMAT_VERSION="1.0">
<SUBJECT record=&quot;3782438&quot;><NAME>ТОВАРИСТВО З ОБМЕЖЕНОЮ ВІДПОВІДАЛЬНІСТЮ &quot;АВГУСТ АГРО&quot;</NAME><SHORT_NAME>ТОВ &quot;АВГУСТ АГРО&quot;</SHORT_NAME><OPF>ТОВАРИСТВО З ОБМЕЖЕНОЮ ВІДПОВІДАЛЬНІСТЮ</OPF><EDRPOU>36146319</EDRPOU><ADDRESS>Україна, 14000, Чернігівська обл., місто Чернігів, вул.Полуботка гетьмана, будинок 6А</ADDRESS><STAN>зареєстровано</STAN><FOUNDING_DOCUMENT_NUM/><EXECUTIVE_POWER/><FOUNDERS><FOUNDER>ОТРОШКО ОЛЕКСАНДР ПЕТРОВИЧ, розмір внеску до статутного фонду - 55000,00 грн.</FOUNDER></FOUNDERS><BENEFICIARIES><BENEFICIARY>Отрошко Олександр Петрович; Україна; Україна, 14032, Чернігівська обл., місто Чернігів, вул.Бєлова Генерала, будинок 25, квартира 50</BENEFICIARY></BENEFICIARIES><ACTIVITY_KINDS><ACTIVITY_KIND><CODE>81.30</CODE><NAME>Надання ландшафтних послуг</NAME></ACTIVITY_KIND><ACTIVITY_KIND><CODE>47.76</CODE><NAME>Роздрібна торгівля квітами, рослинами, насінням, добривами, домашніми тваринами та кормами для них у спеціалізованих магазинах</NAME></ACTIVITY_KIND><ACTIVITY_KIND><CODE>46.22</CODE><NAME>Оптова торгівля квітами та рослинами</NAME></ACTIVITY_KIND><ACTIVITY_KIND><CODE>46.21</CODE><NAME>Оптова торгівля зерном, необробленим тютюном, насінням і кормами для тварин</NAME></ACTIVITY_KIND><ACTIVITY_KIND><CODE>01.61</CODE><NAME>Допоміжна діяльність у рослинництві</NAME></ACTIVITY_KIND><ACTIVITY_KIND><CODE>46.75</CODE><NAME>Оптова торгівля хімічними продуктами</NAME><PRIMARY>так</PRIMARY></ACTIVITY_KIND></ACTIVITY_KINDS><SUPERIOR_MANAGEMENT/><SIGNERS><SIGNER>ОТРОШКО ОЛЕКСАНДР ПЕТРОВИЧ - керівник</SIGNER><SIGNER>ОТРОШКО ОЛЕКСАНДР ПЕТРОВИЧ - представник</SIGNER></SIGNERS><AUTHORIZED_CAPITAL>55000,00</AUTHORIZED_CAPITAL><STATUTE>Діє на підставі установчих документів, затверджених засновниками (учасниками)</STATUTE><REGISTRATION>03.09.2008; 03.09.2008; 10691020000023871</REGISTRATION><MANAGING_PAPER/><BRANCHES/><TERMINATION_STARTED_INFO/><BANKRUPTCY_READJUSTMENT_INFO/><PREDECESSORS/><ASSIGNEES/><TERMINATED_INFO/><TERMINATION_CANCEL_INFO/><CONTACTS>8 067 4271278</CONTACTS><EXCHANGE_DATA><EXCHANGE_ANSWER><AUTHORITY_NAME>ГОЛОВНЕ УПРАВЛІННЯ РЕГІОНАЛЬНОЇ СТАТИСТИКИ</AUTHORITY_NAME><AUTHORITY_CODE>21680000</AUTHORITY_CODE><START_DATE>04.09.2008</START_DATE></EXCHANGE_ANSWER><EXCHANGE_ANSWER><AUTHORITY_NAME>ГОЛОВНЕ УПРАВЛІННЯ ДПС У М.КИЄВІ, ДПІ В ОБОЛОНСЬКОМУ РАЙОНІ (ОБОЛОНСЬКИЙ РАЙОН М.КИЄВА)</AUTHORITY_NAME><AUTHORITY_CODE>43141267</AUTHORITY_CODE><TAX_PAYER_TYPE>Реєстр платників податків</TAX_PAYER_TYPE><START_DATE>04.09.2008</START_DATE><START_NUM>12265</START_NUM></EXCHANGE_ANSWER><EXCHANGE_ANSWER><AUTHORITY_NAME>ГОЛОВНЕ УПРАВЛІННЯ ДПС У М.КИЄВІ, ДПІ В ОБОЛОНСЬКОМУ РАЙОНІ (ОБОЛОНСЬКИЙ РАЙОН М.КИЄВА)</AUTHORITY_NAME><AUTHORITY_CODE>43141267</AUTHORITY_CODE><TAX_PAYER_TYPE>Реєстр платників єдиного внеску</TAX_PAYER_TYPE><START_DATE>04.09.2008</START_DATE><START_NUM>03-42823</START_NUM></EXCHANGE_ANSWER></EXCHANGE_DATA><VP_DATES/><CURRENT_AUTHORITY>Оболонська районна в місті Києві державна адміністрація</CURRENT_AUTHORITY></SUBJECT>
```

Comment: решение **подобной** проблемы совсе необязательно решит вашу проблему. Вам надо разобраться в чем конкретно проблема, а потом решать. И что в вашем случае означает "решить"? Пропустить такую строчку или все-таки попытаться ее обработать?

Comment: А что там в строке 3 колонке 16, не смотрели?

Comment: @CrazyElf да там не понятно как посмотреть, что является строкой, а что колонкой

Comment: @CrazyElf там <subject id=&quot;4342&quot;>...
Полагаю, что проблема в том, что вместо знака " пишется &quot;

Comment: Приложите к вопросу образец файла, с которым возникает проблема. Там и другие элементы могут быть url-encoded, но является ли это проблемой - сказать сложно.

Comment: @CrazyElf приложил